# WCF security and client error

Tags: c#, wcf, security

i have created a wcf service with Message security mode enabled this is my 
service

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMessagingServices
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SendMessage(string from, string to, string message);

        [OperationContract]
        List<Message> GetMessages(string from, string to);

        [OperationContract]
        int DeleteMessages(int[] idList);
    }
}
```

and this is it's config

```
<bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsBinding1">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>



<services>


  <service name="MessagingServices" behaviorConfiguration="SecureServiceBehavior" >
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMessagingServices" bindingConfiguration="wsBinding1" />
    <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetaDataExchange"/>-->
  </service>

</services>


<behaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="httpBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>

    <behavior name="SecureServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="KServic.local" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="AuthenticationHandler, mynamespace" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

everything seems to be fine , i can add service in add service reference in VS 2010 and the proxy is created successively but in client when try to call a service operation i get a error this is the client code

```
ServiceReference1.MessagingServicesClient mscClient = new MessagingServicesClient();

           // mscClient.Open();

            mscClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
            mscClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test";
            mscClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "KService.local");

             // error is here
            var msg = mscClient.SendMessage("rnd.test", "rnd.test", "Hello brother!");

            mscClient.Close();
```

and this is error

***The identity check failed for the outgoing message. The expected identity is 'identity(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/right/possessproperty: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/thumbprint)' for the 'http://192.168.100.24:16027/MessagingServices.svc' target endpoint.***

what's wrong here ? and how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: Why are you setting a Certificate on client-side?

Answer (score 0):

You should set *endpoint identity* at client side when using message security.
The code you provided sets *client credentials*, not an endpoint identity.

See [`<identity>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731721) and [`<certificateReference>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731383) elements in WCF configuration schema, if you want to set up identity via .config file, or [`X509CertificateEndpointIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.x509certificateendpointidentity) class, if you want to set up identity in code:

```
var certificate = ...; // load X509Certificate2 instance from the X509Store
var address = new EndpointAddress(uri, new X509CertificateEndpointIdentity(certificate));
```

Note, that service certificate must be validated before use at client side. For more information, see [`<authentication> of <serviceCertificate>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347703) element page.

Comment: i have created another certificate by MakeCert.exe and then i have installed it in the developer client machine and it worked,

Comment: i have created another certificate by MakeCert.exe and then i have installed it in the developer client machine and it worked, but my test project (client) was console application now i want to use it in silverlight application but a cross-domain policy error occurs in service calling , and a warning created by VS with this content "Incompatible with silverlight 4" ??? what's wrong here ? i need to know more detailed and complete about WCF security. so please introduce me a good book or article about the WCF security .